# Prepared Statement binding of String to Date

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Recently I stumbled upon a code where a parsed string from simple date format was used to bind in a prepared statement to a field of DATETIME type in MySql. How come it doesn't throw any error as ideally it should have been bind to a date type.

The field type is of **DATETIME** in MySql database.

```
ps.setString(index, stringDateObj);
```

Why setString works in this case? Shouldn't it have been `ps.setDate(index, dateObj);` ?

Comment: Preferably, you should be binding the date value directly (not formatting it first), but if the format fits the requirements of the database, it can also be used, but you have a problem if the format ever changes in the database (as apposed to just letting the driver to it's job)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, it is not something I'm doing. I saw existing code where something like that was done. I'm not able to understand why a string is bind without any error for a DATETIME field?

Comment: Think about this, if you weren't using a `PreparedStatement`, then what would you do?  You'd provide the date value in a text format, formatted to the requirements of the database, this is the same thing.  Having said that, you (as a general concept) really shouldn't, as the driver is, as you seem to beware, is fully capable of dealing with `Date` objects by itself, some people just can't seem to get past that idea for some reason.  Is it good?  Not really, but the driver is capable of dealing with it.  It would probably complain if the formatting of the `String` was wrong

Answer (score 2):

Set String will work in all those cases where your *Database* has a conversion pattern for the string format. For formats not known to your database it will break.

You'll also have to deal differently with time zone in that case - that is, if your string format didn't include one.

If you can change the code, I recommend parsing in Java (where you know the format) and passing a java.sql.Date into `PreparedStatement`.